# Can't set wallpaper with Xfce in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, xfce, desktop-background

I recently updated from 14.04 LTS to 15.04 and everything has been working smoothly except for my wallpaper. When I first boot ubuntu my wallpaper is there but after a few minutes it switches over to the default wallpaper for Xfce. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: are you using nautilus?

Comment: I am indeed using nautilus

Answer (score 0):

install gnome-tweak-tool:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

select desktop, and toggle "show icons on desktop" to the off position.